# Jquery toggle effect in IE 8 / 7

Tags: accordion, jquery

I am using the following jquery toogle function to show / hide a detailed list

```
    $('dt').toggle(
function() {
    $(this).next('dd').slideUp();
    $(this).addClass('selectedArrow');

},
function() {
    $(this).next('dd').slideDown();
    $(this).removeClass('selectedArrow');

}
);
```

This adds the selectedArrow class on all browsers except IE7 and IE8, the reason for this class is that has a background image that changes depending on what state the toogle is in,

Any ideas how I can get it to add the class on IE7 / 8 or know of an alternative method of getting the same result.

---

Thanks for your help, managed to get it working in the end, turned out to be a background alignment issue of the arrows in my css

Answer (score 2):

Your code works here in IE6 and IE9 and in IE9's compatibility mode that simulates IE7 and IE8 in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/F3F5E/) so I'm thinking that the issue has to do with something you're not disclosing to us about your actual page, either your HTML or something else about your code.

Here's what I used in my demo to show that it works:

HTML:

```
Click on Coffee or Milk<br><br>
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>- black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

And, I used your exact code:

```
$('dt').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).next('dd').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('selectedArrow');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).next('dd').slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass('selectedArrow');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another solution? Something like:

```
$('#dt').click(function(){
   $(this).next('dd').slideToggle().toggleClass('selectedArrow');
});
```